# Css Rotated Parallelogram With Text

Tags: css, rotation, transform

I have the following css code snippet for creating a diagonal box with text inside.  I would like the top to appear flat (a parallelogram), yet preserve the diagonal nature.

```
.diagonalTextBox {
color: black;
background-color: #fff;
width:50px;
height:20px;
position: absolute;
transform:rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
-webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
-moz-transform: skew(20deg);
-o-transform: skew(20deg);
-ms-transform: skew(20deg);
```

but that would also distort the text...